# In what kind of data structure implemented TCL's array?

Tags: arrays, tcl

Working on the manipulation of very big dates in TCL I am wondering how fast is searching in arrays. Unfortunately the fill up process in arrays is not performs as well as in the other famous scripting languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data structure that Tcl calls an “array” is an associative map from string values to *variables* (and it's considered to be variable-like, in that it has a name and you can do advanced things like attaching a `trace` to it). Under the hood, it's a hash table (and in fact it's one of the fastest hash table implementations of all) so it scales pretty well as the number of elements increases.

But it's not the same as the arrays you'd find in a language like C, Java, C#, Python, … The thing in Tcl that most closely matches those is the *list*, which is a value (i.e., nameless, automatically serializable) that holds a compact map from “small” integers (i.e., indices) to values. It's much lighter weight than a Tcl array (indeed, it's implemented using a C array).

They don't support the same set of operations. Indeed, there's a third data structure in Tcl to be aware of: the *dictionary*. That's a value that is associative map from strings to values. It's also implemented using a hash table (using the same super-fast algorithm that Tcl uses for arrays) though with some customization so that there's a fixed order of iteration (the insertion order, because that's got good properties when you round-trip the serialization).

You can put lists in dictionaries and dictionaries in lists. You can put either in an array element. But you *can't* put an array (or element of an array) in either a list or a dictionary; the best you can do is to put the name of the array in (as that's just a plain old string).

---

### Performance Comparison

Lists are the fastest to create (especially with `lrepeat`) and have both fast update and fast lookup operations. Provided you're working by index. Searching the contents requires a linear scan.

Arrays and dictionaries are slower to create — which is slowest depends on *exactly* what you're doing — but both support super-fast lookup and update by key. (Testing for presence of a key also does a lookup; it's algorithmically almost identical to a read.) Searching for the presence of a particular payload is *still* slow; it still requires a linear scan.

Note when timing things in Tcl: *always* time a call to a procedure, as procedures get more heavily optimised than free code.

```
proc doStuffList {size value1 value2} {
    for {set i 0} {$i < $size} {incr i} {
        lappend theList $i
    }
    return [list [lindex $theList $value1] [lindex $theList $value2]]
}
proc doStuffDict {size value1 value2} {
    for {set i 0} {$i < $size} {incr i} {
        dict set theDict $i $i
    }
    return [list [dict get $theDict $value1] [dict get $theDict $value2]]
}
proc doStuffArray {size value1 value2} {
    for {set i 0} {$i < $size} {incr i} {
        set theArray($i) $i
    }
    return [list $theArray($value1) $theArray($value2)]
}

puts "lists: [time {doStuffList 500 150 450} 1000]"
puts "dicts: [time {doStuffDict 500 150 450} 1000]"
puts "arrays: [time {doStuffArray 500 150 450} 1000]"
```

On this laptop, I get this output:

```
lists: 58.565204 microseconds per iteration
dicts: 114.074002 microseconds per iteration
arrays: 118.863908 microseconds per iteration
```

**But be aware that which is the best option depends *totally* on the details of what you're doing.** Use the data structure that fits your algorithm best; fitting well will ensure that it performs well for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple test that shows the array and list performance. My initial test showed that list filled faster than array.  Array picks up some speed on the search time.

array.tcl

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh

set array_time [time {
        array unset my_array
        for {set i 0} {$i < 365} {incr i} {
                set "my_array($i)" $i
        }
        set a [info exists my_array(180)]
        set b [info exists my_array(366)]
} 100]

set list_time [time {
        set my_list [list]
        for {set i 0} { $i < 365} {incr i} {
                lappend my_list $i
        }
        set x [lsearch $my_list 180]
        set y [lsearch $my_list 366]

} 100]

puts "$a, $b"
puts "$x, $y"

puts "array: $array_time
```

output:

```
% ./array.tcl
1, 0
180, -1
array: 360.54830999999996 microseconds per iteration
list: 362.89529000000005 microseconds per iteration
```